# Debugging XSLT with extension objects in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, xslt, extension-objects

I'm currently working on a project that involves a lot of XSLT transformations and I *really* need a debugger (I have XSLTs that are 1000+ lines long and I didn't write them :-).

The project is written in C# and makes use of extension objects:

```
xslArg.AddExtensionObject("urn:<obj>", new <Obj>());
```

From my knowledge, in this situation Visual Studio is the only tool that can help me debug the transformations step-by-step. The static debugger is no use because of the extension objects (it throws an error when it reaches elements that reference their namespace). Fortunately, I've found [this thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c880a4ab-327f-4a52-af4a-1a3fbb36c974/debug-xslt-with-extension-objects?forum=xmlandnetfx) which gave me a starting point (at least I know it can be done).

After searching MSDN, I found the criteria that makes stepping into the transform possible. They are listed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xsl.xslcompiledtransform.-ctor?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8). In short:

- the XML and the XSLT must be loaded via a class that has the `IXmlLineInfo` interface (`XmlReader` & co.)
- the XML resolver used in the `XSLTCompiledTransform` constructor is file-based (`XmlUriResolver` should work).
- the stylesheet should be on the local machine or on the intranet (?)

From what I can tell, I fit all these criteria, but it still doesn't work. The relevant code samples are posted below:

```
// [...]

xslTransform = new XslCompiledTransform(true);

xslTransform.Load(XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(contents)), null, new BaseUriXmlResolver(xslLocalPath));

// [...]

// I already had the xml loaded in an xmlDocument 
// so I have to convert to an XmlReader
XmlTextReader r = new XmlTextReader(new StringReader(xmlDoc.OuterXml));

XsltArgumentList xslArg = new XsltArgumentList();
xslArg.AddExtensionObject("urn:[...]", new [...]());
xslTransform.Transform(r, xslArg, context.Response.Output);
```

I really don't get what I'm doing wrong. I've checked the interfaces on both `XmlReader` objects and they implement the required one. Also, `BaseUriXmlResolver` inherits from `XmlUriResolver` and the stylesheet is stored locally. The screenshot below is what I get when stepping into the `Transform` function. First I can see the stylesheet code after stepping through the parameters (on template-match), I get this:

[image: The error I get when I step into the stylesheet]

If anyone has any idea why it doesn't work or has an alternative way of getting it to work I'd be much obliged :).

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about usage of extension objects but as I understand your problem is with debugging of XSLT transformation in code in VS2010.
Here is the function that we use to debug XSLT transformation:

```
 public string ApplyTransformation(string inputFilePath, string xsltFileContent)
    {
        XslCompiledTransform transform = new XslCompiledTransform(debugEnabled);

        File.WriteAllText(xsltTempFilePath,xsltFileContent);
        transform.Load(xsltTempFilePath, XsltSettings.TrustedXslt, new XmlUrlResolver());

        XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(inputFilePath);
        StringWriter output = new StringWriter();
        XmlWriter writer =  XmlWriter.Create(output,transform.OutputSettings);
        transform.Transform(reader,writer);
        return output.ToString();
    }
```

Unfortunately, there is a [bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/557335/xslt-debugger-doesnt-work-with-in-memory-transformation) with VS2010 XSLT debugger which will make your debugging experience worse than in VS2008.

Comment: Regarding the bug: Has this been working with VS 2008? I was only getting it to work with the XSLT being loaded from a file on disc.

Answer (score 0):

Consider debugging using XML Spy XSLT debugger. It works for me all the time.

Comment: After a quick look, I couldn't find anything related to extension objects. Does it support them?